# How to scale a sprite(CCSprite) in cocos2d-x(android) ?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am trying to scale a background sprite (which uses a larger size image resource) to a lower size but unable to do that.

I am doing it as follows :

```
CCSprite *splashSprite =CCSprite::spriteWithFile("splashscreen.jpg");
 splashSprite->setPosition(ccp(240, 150));
 splashSprite->setScale(0.5f);
```

But sprite remains its original size. No change. 
Please help.

Comment: You can not change the original size by using 'setScale()'.It is only for display.

Comment: would you mind to try using a png? cocos2d-x doesn't support jpg very well. I couldn't find any problem with your code.

Comment: try with CCScaleTo function with some action on your sprite ..

Comment: @SpencerWong  setscale function works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this way . it works

```
CCSprite* splashSprite= CCSprite::create("splashscreen.png");
splashSprite->setPosition(ccp(240, 150));
splashSprite->setScale(0.5f);
this->addChild(splashSprite, 0);
```